# When i read the xml file it reads duplicates of the element

Tags: c#, winforms

When i run my program and click on the second tab multiple times it creates labels x amount of times and im unsure if theirs a way to sort of only read the xml only once... I tried using a .close method but that did not work for me... any help would be appreciated thank you

```
       private void tabPage2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
        {


            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("xmldoc.xml");
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("check/tick/mark"))
            {

                Label l = new Label();
                System.Drawing.Point l1 = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 48 + a);
                l.Location = l1;
                l.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("score").InnerText;
                tabPage2.Controls.Add(l);
                a += 25;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the xml reading in a different function. Create a variable to store whether or not you have already read the xml. Only invoke the xml reading function if it has not already been called.

Comment: hmm yea that makes sence let me give it a shot , thanx

Answer (score 0):

This happens beacuse your code read multiple-times the same xmldocument so try:

```
   bool read = false;

   void ReadXmDocument()
   {
       using(XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument())
       {
          xmlDoc.Load("xmldoc.xml");
          foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("check/tick/mark"))
          {
                Label l = new Label();
                System.Drawing.Point l1 = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 48 + a);
                l.Location = l1;
                l.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("score").InnerText;
                tabPage2.Controls.Add(l);
                a += 25;
          }

          read = true;
       }
   }

   private void tabPage2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if(tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2 && read == false) ReadXmlDocument();
   }
```